# ¿Cómo terminar o eliminar un hilo por completo en java?

Tags: java, hilos

Al momento de inicializar un nuevo Thread, luego que se ejecute el método `run()` por completo, ¿cómo puedo eliminar este hilo?

```
public void iniciarHilo(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            //Codigo 
        }
    }).start();

    //Una vez ejecutado el código del método run, necesito eliminar el hilo, o detenerlo
}
```

Igual de esta manera

```
public void iniciarHilo(){

    Thread hilo = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            //Código 
        }
    });
    hilo.start();
    //Eliminar este hilo

}
```

Lo que sucede es que cada vez que se cumpla una decisión específica llamo a un método que dentro de éste inicio un nuevo hilo, para eliminar componentes del frame con una pequeña demora entre cada uno y que se vea bien, pero entre más caigo en esa decisión, el programa se queda trabado.

Creo que es porque los hilos quedan ejecutándose, porque al eliminar el hilo del método y sólo dejar el código del proceso, el programa va estupendo.

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres lograr con los hilos es actualizar tu frame mientras se hace "otra cosa" con otro hilo? Te lo pregunto porque dices que es _"para eliminar componentes del frame"_. Ten en cuenta que cuando lanzas un hilo con `start()` pierdes el control del orden en que se ejecutan los hilos, pero si llega el final de `run()` que también lo dices, el hilo muere, con lo que no estaría ejecutandose nada sino es por _"una pequeña demora entre cada uno"_ que no sabemos cómo haces y que puede que dejes dormido o en espera y sea lo que hace que _"se quede trabado"_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No puedes mandar a terminar la ejecución de un hilo. Lo único que puedes hacer es asegurarte que la ejecución del método `run` (por implementar `Runnable` o por extender de `Thread`) tenga alguna manera de finalizar. Al finalizar la ejecución de este método, el hilo terminará su ejecución. Esto es, en lugar de tener algo como

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        //tarea infinita que nunca va a terminar...
    }
}
```

Por lo menos tener algo como (esto en realidad es demasiado básico y no apto para aplicaciones del mundo real, pero ilustra una forma de detener y terminar la ejecución del hilo):

```
volatile boolean ejecutar = true;

@Override
public void run() {
    while(ejecutar) {
        //tarea infinita que nunca va a terminar...
    }
}

public void detener() {
    ejecutar = false;
}
```

Puesto que mencionas el uso de frames, te informo que no es recomendable crear `Thread`s directamente y modificar los frames desde allí puesto que Swing utiliza un hilo diferente para la administración de los componentes visuales. Lo mejor sería usar [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), pero para un mejor detalle necesitaríamos conocer más de tu caso en particular.

---

Olvida el usode los métodos [`Thread#stop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop--) y [`Thread#suspend`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend--). La documentación oficial explica claramente que **no debes usar estos métodos** (revisar el contenido de los enlaces provistos). Inclusive hay un artículo dedicado a esto: [Why are `Thread.stop`, `Thread.suspend` and `Thread.resume` Deprecated?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) que traducido significa *¿Por qué los métodos `Thread.stop`, `Thread.suspend` and `Thread.resume` están depreciados?*.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta amigo!, me ha servido mucho. Saludos!

Comment: Saben como hacerlo en el caso que hay varios hilos con  metodo run infinito ejecutandose, por favor

Answer (score 3):

#### `stop()`

Este método provoca que el hilo se detenga de manera inmediata. A menudo constituye una manera brusca de detener un hilo, especialmente si este método se ejecuta sobre el hilo en curso. En tal caso, la línea inmediatamente posterior a la llamada al método stop() no llega a ejecutarse jamás, pues el contexto del hilo muere antes de que stop() devuelva el control. Una forma más elegante de detener un hilo es utilizar alguna variable que ocasione que el método run() termine de manera ordenada. En realidad, nunca se debería recurrir al uso de este método.

#### `suspend()`

El método suspend() es distinto de stop(). suspend() toma el hilo y provoca que se detenga su ejecución sin destruir el hilo de sistema subyacente, ni el estado del hilo anteriormente en ejecución. Si la ejecución de un hilo se suspende, puede llamarse a resume() sobre el mismo hilo para lograr que vuelva a ejecutarse de nuevo.

http://dhw.umh.es/alex-bia/teaching/PC/material/hilos_tutorial-java/cap10-2.htm

Comment: Voto en contra. Esta respuesta es muy mala. Principalmente porque los autores de Java indican que estos métodos **no deben usarse**.

Comment: precisamente se dice al final. Lee, dice: En realidad, nunca se debería recurrir al uso de este método

Comment: Entonces si nunca se debería recurrir a ejecutarse ese método, ¿por qué lo publicas como la solución al problema?

Answer (score 1):

podes hacer algo asi:

```
private static volatile boolean thState; // este booleano va a controlar la ejecucion dentro del metodo run();
static Thread th; // creas el hilo sin iniciarlo

public static synchronized void thStart() {
    thState = true; // estableces el booleano a true, para q se ejecute el hilo

    th = new Thread(new BatOrExeEvents()); // inicias el hilo
    th.start(); // lo ejecutas
}

public static synchronized void thStop() {
    thState = false; // estableces el booleano a false para detener la ejecucion del hilo

    try {
        th.join(); // interrumpis la ejecucion
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(thState) {
        // el contenido se va a ejecutar mientras el booleano sea verdadero
    }
}
```

Cuando quieras iniciar o detener el hilo, usa los metodos que estan arriba, no uses hilo.start(); o hilo.stop();. También puedes usar el booleano para remplazar el método hilo.isAlive();

***Aclaraciones:***
al booleano lo inicias como "volatile" para que mientras se este leyendo o escribiendo, no se pueda modificar su valor. Es para evitar errores.
Y los métodos para iniciar y parar el hilo, los inicias como "synchronized" para que no se puedan ejecutar a la vez, puesto que causaría un error.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo los 3, supongo que es obvio para que es cada uno, aunque no es una buena práctica detener un hilo y eliminarlo, debería terminarse de forma natural.

```
hilo.stop();

hilo.suspend();

hilo.destroy();
```

Saludos

Comment: ¿Por qué no se considera una buena práctica terminar el hilo de forma manual?

Comment: Voto en contra. Esta respuesta es muy mala. Principalmente porque los autores de Java indican que estos métodos **no deben usarse**.

Comment: yo respondí lo que él pidió y con las aclaraciones de que no se deberían usar osea hice esas aclaraciones antes de poner los códigos, de ahí a que los use o no depende de él, otra cosa sería si no lo hubiere aclarado

Comment: Es como que OP necesite matar un insecto y le digas "puedes usar una granada o un lanza misiles, ah pero si sales herido en el proceso es tu problema".

Comment: Si el tipo hizo una pregunta y se le responde lo que pregunto a mi parecer, si hice la aclaración no veo lo malo, es como que te diga:

Comment: Necesito hacer una pagina responsive, puedo usar medias en css, y pues la respuesta sería si y le mostras como y al final si quieres le aclaras "te conviene usar boostrapp" (es un ejemplo nada mas)